# Skipping indexing of some values in an array, but keeping them in _source

Tags: elasticsearch

In ElasticSearch, I am trying to index documents like:

```
{
  "tags": [
    {
       "value": "...",
       "quality": 0.7
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

I would like that `_source` contains the full document, but that that only those `value`s are indexed which have `quality` above some threshold. I read documentation and it looks to me that if I modify input document in any way before indexing (e.g., filter out `value`s), then the modified document will be stored under `_source`, not the original one.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: So, if I got this right, you're after a dynamic way of indexing a specific field depending on the value of that field? Above threshold => index, below threshold => don't index, is that correct? But always index the full source document

Comment: Indexing a specific field depending on the value of the sibling field, yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is one way to achieve this. By default the `tags` structure is disabled in the mapping (i.e. not indexed). Then by leveraging ingest processors, you can create a secondary `tags` structure (which I called `indexedTags`) that will only contain the tag elements whose `quality` component is higher than a given threshold.

So the mapping should look like this:

```
PUT test 
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "tags": {
        "enabled": false,        <--- won't be indexed at all, but still present in _source
        "properties": {
          "value": {
            "type": "text"
          },
          "quality": {
            "type": "float"
          }
        }
      },
      "indexedTags": {           <--- will only contain indexable values above threshold
        "properties": {
          "value": {
            "type": "text"
          },
          "quality": {
            "type": "float"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then, we need to create an ingest pipeline that allows us to filter the right tag values. The following ingest processor uses a script processor to create the `indexedTags` array out of the `tags` one, and it will only contain elements whose `quality` field is above a defined threshold (e.g. 0.6 in this case):

```
PUT _ingest/pipeline/quality-threshold
{
  "processors": [
    {
      "script": {
        "source": """
          ctx.indexedTags = ctx.tags.stream().filter(t -> t.quality > params.threshold).collect(Collectors.toList());
        """,
        "params": {
          "threshold": 0.6
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Finally, we can leverage that ingest pipeline while indexing documents:

```
PUT test/_doc/1?pipeline=quality-threshold
{
  "tags": [
    {
      "value": "test",
      "quality": 0.5
    },
    {
      "value": "test2",
      "quality": 0.8
    }
  ]
}
```

When running the above command, the whole `tags` array will still be present in the `_source` but it won't be indexed. What will be indexed, however, is another array called `indexedTags` which will only contain the second element (i.e. `test2`), because its `quality` value is 0.8 and that's higher than the 0.6 threshold.

The document looks like this:

```
  {
    "_index" : "test",
    "_type" : "_doc",
    "_id" : "1",
    "_score" : 0.2876821,
    "_source" : {
      "indexedTags" : [
        {
          "value" : "test2",
          "quality" : 0.8
        }
      ],
      "tags" : [
        {
          "value" : "test",
          "quality" : 0.5
        },
        {
          "value" : "test2",
          "quality" : 0.8
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

You can now see that the first element `test` is not indexed at all by searching for

```
GET test/_search?q=test
=> No results
```

While searching for `test2` will retrieve your document:

```
GET test/_search?q=test2
=> Returns document 1
```

Comment: Thanks. This looks very detailed. Is there a way to not store  `indexedTags` into `_source`?

Comment: Can you explain what kind of query you'd like to make on this data?

Comment: The query examples you made is the answer is pretty much it. I know I can hide the ` indexedTags` field from `_source` when fetching, but I would prefer not having to save it (just to save space) if not necessary.

Comment: Ok, you only need to query `value` and never `quality`. Is `tags` of type `nested` or is that simply of type `object`?

Comment: That is a great question. I have indeed multiple `tags`-like fields, some of them are `nested` but some of them are just `object`. So if there is a solution which works for `nested` that would be great, but also just for `object` would be good to know.

Comment: If you have `nested` data, there's a reason why they are nested (i.e. querying on 2+ fields of nested documents), how do your queries on nested data look like?

Comment: They look like `{"type": "length", "numericValue": 13, "quality": 0.7}`. So an array of possible typed values and queries then filter documents based on type + value combination. For filters it is easy to add `quality` to the filter. The problem is that some look also like `{"type": "description", "textValue": "bunch of text", "quality": 0.9}` and I would like to have full text search over `textValue` values as well (field name is fixed based for those I want full text search over), but only for those with high `quality`.

Comment: So, if I get this right, you run a full-text search on the `textValue` of all `type: description` elements whose `quality` is above a certain threshold. So we could actually concatenate all `textValue` data together into a single field (provided quality is good) and perform the full text search on that field. Right?

Comment: There are different types which can use `textValue`. It is true that we could combine them all together because I always search only on all of them together, but that would destroy statistics for terms, no? Like, if there was no `quality` field and I would use `nested` and have `textValue` as text field, that would not be the same as using `object` and having a `textValue` or even concatenating all values?

Comment: That's why it's important to know not only **what** you're searching but also **how** you're searching. It would be great to understand your use case more precisely and how you search and what you expect when searching. I got the point about only searching `textValue` with a sufficiently high `quality`, but how your queries should look like is still an unknown to me. Please shed some light on that.

Comment: OK, thank you for all the input. I think I will have to go back to the drawing board a bit. To figure out some details here. I am still designing the structure and queries so there is some flexibility. Thanks.

Comment: Sure @Mitar no worries, let us know once you know more